# Scringo: openChat function doesn't work

Tags: android, scringo

I am using the library scringo on Android. "openChat" function doesn't seem to be working. It does absolutely nothing. Here is my code.

I read through their API:
http://www.scringo.com/docs/api/android/

openChat function should open the 1-on-1 chat with the other user. But that doesnt happen. Nothing happens. All the other functions are working fine.
It doesn't even log any errors or warning.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Scringo scringo;
private Activity mainactivity;
private Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainactivity = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    Scringo.setAppId("MY-APP-ID");
    Scringo.setDebugMode(true);
    scringo = new Scringo(this);
    scringo.init();
    scringo.addSidebar();
    Scringo.loginWithEmail("a@testapp.com", "hi", new ScringoSignUpListener(){
        @Override
        public void onError(String arg0) {  
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
            Log.w("user",Scringo.getUserId());  
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //I am using the ID of another user.
    //This does not work. Nothing happens. No error or warning either.
    Scringo.openChat(this, "Qk8vJs4fRE");  

    //This works fine. 
    //Scringo.openChatRooms(this); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the openChat after getting the user:

```
Scringo.getUserByScringoId("SOME_ID...", new ScringoGetUserListener() {
    @Override
    public void gotUser(ScringoUser user) {
        Scringo.openChat(MainActivity.this, "SOME_ID...");
    }
});
```